# How can I convert the button text for a timestamp to a integer in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(".BtnRed, .BtnTime1, .BtnTime2").click(function() { 
    if ($(this).text() == "Green") { 
        $(this).text(new Date()); 
    } else { 
        $(this).text("Green"); 
    }; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border = "1px">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <td>HospitalNumber</td>
 <td>PatientName</td>
 <td>Procedure</td>
 <td>Notes</td>
 <td>Ward/Unit</td>
 <td>Made Ready</td>
 <td>Pre-Recovery</td> 
 <td>GA</td>
 <td>Time-In Room</td>
 <td>Time-Out Room</td>
 <td>Post Recovery</td>
 <td>Back On Ward</td>
 <td>Time Difference</td>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td><br/></td>
 <td><br/></td>
 <td><br/></td>
 <td><br/></td>
 <td><br/></td>
 <td>
 <select>
 <option class="MRR" value="Red - Not seen/Ready DNA">Red - Not seen/Ready DNA</option>
    <option class="MRA"   value="Canula" >Cannula</option>
    <option class="MRA" value="Consent" >Consent</option>
 <option class="MRG" value="Green">Green</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 <td>
 <select>
    <option class="PRA" value="Delay" >Delay</option>
    <option class="PRA" value="Stemi" >Stemi</option>
 <option class="PRA" value="Consultants">Consultants</option>
 <option class="PRA" value="Overrun">Overrun</option>
 <option class="PRG" value="Green">Green</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 <td><button class = "BtnRed btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
 <td><button class = "BtnTime1 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
 <td><button class = "BtnTime2 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
 <td>
 <select>
 <option class="PRRR" value="Red - Recovery Post GA">Red - Recovery Post GA</option>
    <option class="PRRA" value="Monitor (Lab)">Monitor (Lab)</option>
    <option class="PRRA" value="A/W Bed" >A/W Bed</option>
 <option class="PRRA" value="Medical Review">Medical Review</option>
 <option class="PRRG" value="Green">Green</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 <td><button class = "BtnRed btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
 <td class = "TimeDiff"><br/></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody> 
 </table>
```

Hi, I have some jQuery code that calls classes ".BtnRed, .BtnTime1, .BtnTime2", when clicked on a button it displays a timestamp in string format. I would like to convert the format to a numeric value (such as a integer) so I can minus both dates and work out the time difference.

Many thanks!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp

Comment: Also, for all dates manipulation (time difference, etc), just use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/). It's got it all sorted out for you already.

Answer (score 1):

Use get time method for the same:

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getTime());
```

More details can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)